# Uninstalling mono.net

Tags: xamarin, mono

I have uninstalled mono.net (OSX) following [the instructions from the mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/), but when I do `mono --version` in terminal I am still getting a response:

> Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Fri Jul 10 20:47:12 PDT 2015)
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
>     TLS:           normal
>     SIGSEGV:       altstack
>     Notification:  kqueue
>     Architecture:  amd64
>     Disabled:      none
>     Misc:          softdebug
>     LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
>     GC:            sgen

How do I totally remove mono.net?

(Ultimately I am trying to update my running framework to Mono v4.6)

Comment: which platform (Mac or Windows)?

Comment: OSX - updated the question

Comment: @SushiHangover I already tried that.

Comment: If you run `which mono` what does it return? Have you installed mono via `homebrew` or `ports`?

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, that was it. I had installed mono via homebrew, but uninstalled that and rebooted and v4.0 version is gone. I have tried to install 4.6 but that is not working yet...